# Android action bar crashes with theme

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I use Google's support libraries of version `23.1.0`.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

I am reusing a theme file that worked with versions of the support libraries prior to the introduction of material design.

```
<style name="AppTheme.StatusBarOverlay.Main" parent="@style/AppTheme.Main">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.Main" parent="@style/AppBaseTheme.Main">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
<style name="AppBaseTheme.Main" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Main">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/main_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/main_color_dk</item>
</style>
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Main" parent="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Main" />
<style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Main" parent="@style/Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat" />
<style name="Theme.CustomDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/trans_draw</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

I made my `MainActivity` use the style by setting the theme in the **manifest**

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.StatusBarOverlay.Main" >
    </activity>
```

When the action bar was retrieved

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

the following exception was raised.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:423)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.initWindowDecorActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:173)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.getSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:89)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:79)
            at com.dynamicwebapac.commerce.mobile.custom.CustomActivity.setupActionBar(CustomActivity.java:39)
            at com.dynamicwebapac.commerce.mobile.custom.CustomActivity.onCreate(CustomActivity.java:25)
            at com.dynamicwebapac.commerce.mobile.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:181)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

What happened to the Android support library after material design was introduced? How can I solve my current problem?

Comment: <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

Answer (score 1):

Using the new material support library, we set up themes like this **styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Also in the **manifest**

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

And then we use the **Toolbar** as the action bar .Do this in your parent layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

And we set it up in our **Java source** using

```
Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry it happens with most of us. I'd like to start with reason of this problem.

The Material Design is in the favour of using `Toolbar` which is more flexible,...etc hence the themes or styles provided by `AppCompat` library are without an `ActionBar` or you can say a support `ActionBar` is provided and hence e need to disable the system default `ActionBar`.

Now follow any of the 2 steps below as suggested by [Colns Abt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4485137/colns-abt):

1. Add any style which has `NoActionBar` at the ending like `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`

   OR
2. Add the following lines in your custom `style`

   ```
   <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
   ```

Further follow steps given by [Colns Abt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4485137/colns-abt).